# How to consolidate rows with same values in an Excel table?

Tags: excel

I am trying to consolidate rows that contain the same values in an Excel table.

[image]

I want to consolidate **just** the Code column that have the same values, so that I get the sum for each Code category *1*, *2*, *3*, like the image below:

[image]

How do I implement this in Excel (without using VBA)? I tried the consolidating feature in Excel but it did not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A pivot table should be able to do that

Comment: Can I make it work without using a pivot table?

Comment: You could either through VBA (macro) or a lot of manual effort.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/405555/how-can-i-group-by-and-sum-a-column-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

You could use subtotals like this...

[image]